# Zoomed in page in browser

Tags: css, responsive-design, responsive, responsibility

When I run VScode live server, the whole page is too large and I don't have a responsive web page **however** in DevTools it work just fine.

**This is how page look in my screen**
[image: This is how page look in my screen]

**This is how it shows in DevTools**
[image: This is how it shows in DevTools]

**This is *CSS* media query**

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
  .section-center {
    width: 95vw;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  }
  .photo {
    height: 150px;
  }
}
```

Comment: "I don't have a responsive web page" Uh, yes you do. Try docking your devtools at the bottom and see what happens. To do that, click the vertical dots and click the 'dock side' on the right.

Comment: Oh, I just noticed the "Dimensions" setting at the top. Play with that too.

Comment: Thank you for helping me, Yes, it was my "Dimension" setting of the browser, I appreciate you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was "Dimensions" setting of the browser

use `"ctrl" + "+"` and `"ctrl" + "-"` to see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's related to this:

[image: 57&]

Also make sure you have:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

inside your `head` tag.

Comment: It was the "Dimensions" setting of the browser, Thanks for putting in your time and answering me

Comment: @mohsenrostami "upvotes" are a better thanking mechanism. You're welcome.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't upvote because I don't have enough reputation to do so.

Comment: @mohsenrostami Not even mark as answer? lol

Comment: In my case, your answer wasn't correct, The DevTool was okay, but the browser page had an issue, if it was, I surely mark your answer.

Comment: @mohsenrostami Who said it was about DevTools? Your page was zoomed in 57%. I suggest you hop around SO and get more comfortable with it before posting.

Comment: That 57% zoomed which you put a red line around it, was in my DevTools! and I tried it which did not work. It wasn't my web page, and to be sure of it I just zoomed my page to 500% on this page, and when I opened the DevTools, that percentage you mentioned wasn't changed, you can try it too.